# Is it possible to make a disk into a named disk on VMware vCloud Director without redeploying a VM?

Tags: vmware

I've heard VMware has lots of fancy features such as live migration of VMs.

Is it possible to change a disk attached to a VM into a named disk without deleting the VM (powering off the VM in my case would be fine, but interested in the limitations if it's possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is possible, but not by some VMware method.

Something like:

- Attach a new named disk, power off the VM.
- Boot the VM from https://gparted.org/index.php.
- Copy the data from the old disk to the new.
- Power off the VM. Remove the original disk. Power on.